# Best way to secure documents?

Tags: file-access, drm, documents

I'm currently tasked with securing our documents stored in our NAS.

Basically, the minimum requirements that is needed are;

1) Watermarking Ability(Any file viewed/downloaded or printed will have the user's name, IP and Time/Date watermarked on the document)

2) Restriction(Not all users can view/download certain files)

I've toyed with XRDP and Ubuntu, so users have to remote into the desktop to be able to access the files, I've even installed Screenlets and used a widget to display their name on the screen but, I've been having issues getting it to work properly.

Can anyone recommend me a good solution to secure the documents? Preferably open-source and with an online document viewer, so there is no need to download the document to view it.

EDIT: Additional information. The document types will be mainly PDF, doc, docx, ppt, pptx, odt, etc. I've tried multiple solutions but, most of them either don't have the watermarking capability or, are not on-premise.

Comment: Can you be more specific in your question? Are we talking about PDF files only? Images only? Office documents?

Comment: @KevinMorssink Thanks, I've added more information. Let me know if I should add anymore things.

Answer (score 1):

You're describing a basic content/document management system that implements a watermarking library (and online document viewer). This could be created and deployed in a few hours by someone with any coding knowledge. (I get the impression you're more of a sysadmin?)

Basically you deploy something like Drupal to serve as a frontend and handle user authentication and access control. You serve up a list of directories as pages, the user navigates to the file they want, you have a library that can modify files that appends a watermark to the metadata and serves it to the user.

Uses entirely open-source tools but requires a little elbow grease on your part, unless you want to hire a college student to write it for beer money.

Comment: You're right. I'm mostly a sysadmin with a little basic knowledge on coding. Hmm, I didn't think about using drupal. I might take a look into that and see if it's possible. Thanks!

Comment: Adding watermark to a document is not very difficult. However, making the watermark non removable is not that easy, and is probably impossible. You can't reliably detect data leakage using watermark.